# How to render html content in Vaadin TextField

Tags: java, vaadin-flow

What i'm trying to do is really simple: render html tag in `TextField` or `TextArea`.

But after googling for a long time i'm surprised to find out that Vaadin seems not to support it.Vaadin `ComboBox` or `ListBox` provides `.setRender()` method to render content in whatever the way i want. But `TextField` or `TextArea` do not have functions like that.I wonder is there any way to do this?

Vaadin `TextField` supports custom theme , but it didn't work when rendering.

```java
textArea.addThemeVariants(TextAreaVariant.MATERIAL_ALWAYS_FLOAT_LABEL);
```

Answer (score 1):

TextField and TextArea are fields to edit plain text.

If you want to display html content, there is [Html component](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/13.0.8/com/vaadin/flow/component/Html.html) in Flow to do that.

If you want to edit html content there is separate [RichTextEditor](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadin-rich-text-editor) for doing that.

Also if you allow user to input the html, remember to sanitize the html before displaying it with e.g. Jsoup in order to avoid xss i.e. JavaScript injection issues.

Comment: Thx so much for the answer. I'm trying to bind TextArea content to a button clicked event.Html component cannot be changed after initialization.And i use TextArea only to present data so RichTextEditor is not eligible for that.

Comment: @yadancenick If it is really just about displaying (not editing) then you can use the Html component. If data changes, simply replace the component with a new updated Html component. E.g. VerticalLayout supports `replace(oldComponent, newComponent)` method for that.